# case statements with switch - case or if-else - best design?

Tags: java

I am trying to explain my design problem with an example.

Assume I have 5 parents [1,2,3,4,5]. Each parent has n children. children is like [a,b,c,d,e,f].

I am trying to write something

```
 Map<String, String> children = parentDataHolder.getParent(parentType).getChildren();
 switch(parentType){
      case 1:
          if(partent1.contains(childType1)){
          }
          //Similarly for all child types
      case 2:
      case 3:
         .......
 }
```

Here, Parent types are fixed. Child types are dynamic. I am getting in a map. For each map, I have to check whether child is present. If so, I have to take action according to child type.

Which design would be better? Above design doesn't look good for me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

parentHolder is an object which has methods to get parent type and children types.
eg:

```
 {
     parentType: '1',
     children:{
       "a":"fileOne.xml",
       "c" : "fileTwo.gz"
     }
  }
```

Once I received this json, I am storing the children values in a `Map` and then I am getting the parentType and passing to switch condition.

Inside switch cases, I have to apply logic for children. The above example has two children. In some other cases, parentType 1 will have a,b,c as children. So It should be generic.

Comment: This is too abstract and vague.  Show us the class definitions of `Parent` and `Child` and explain what `parentType` is.  The question is not answerable in its present state.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am editing. Please wait.

Comment: If each parent/child combination will be handled by separate logic, then what you have isn't bad at all IMO.  If so, there is no avoiding specifying such logic.

Comment: @JimGarrison Please see my edit and let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes. For each parent and it's children logic is separare. But if children is C, then C logic is same for all parent who has C as children.

Comment: Use factory pattern

Comment: @Gops AB : if else or switch statements are ok for situations where we know that the number of cases are fixed and the code for handling each case is also more or less same, swich is better than if else due to improved readability. But both of these should be avoided in case we see that number of cases would be added in future or code to handle cases needs to change, in such cases we have to modify classes just to add new case and to modify any one of the case handling. In such cases abstraction should be used, refer my answer below for more. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42106953/504133

Comment: Hope it will be helpful and if so you may wish to upvote or mark the answer as acceted

Answer (score 1):

As a guide `switch` is better than `if-else` statements as it is more readable.

Axis of change should be identified and both of these (if else and switch)  should be avoided if we find during initial requirement analysis or later with requirement changes  coming that there are new cases being added.

In such a case we need to respect `open close principle`. Swich case statements are not only bad as ocp is voilated but also is prone to errors, if we miss to add a new case at some place then issues may occur.

In such a scenario the cases must be handled through abstraction ( try to protect yourself from changes by abstrating what can change).

You can define a (abstract) parent class for such cases and each case can be mapped to a separate sub class.
Suppose we had a case x : // contents;. Contents can be put in the implementation of the abstract method which we can have in the parent class. In case we have a new case added we can easily define a new class and provide the implementation. The client code should be dependent only upon abstract parent class amd concrete classes can be injected during run time.

Answer (score 0):

Following is just about using `switch` or using `if else` since there are object oriented alternatives addressing more suitable extensibility and maintainability than `switch` and `if else` statements.

Talking about wide solution space complexity wise `switch` statement has an improved complexity than `if else` statements. Summary of technical details is that `switch` statement relies on an indexed solutions space (a jump table with `case` values being indexes) instead of traveling all branches until the matching one. For a narrow solutions space `if else` complexity is better.

Readability wise the `if else` statement has an improved readability since the statement is placed at the beginning of the code block to run while with `switch` statement each `case` must have a start and a close statement (`case` and `break`) that could be interlaced (multiple `case` statements having one `break` statement) making cumbersome to follow the code block to run from its opening to its close.

The best design between the two is a choice between performance (that varies with the solutions space dimension) and readability. Are there enough values to make use of `switch` statement benefits? Or is a facile read preferred regardless of the performance improvements?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking about which is best, think about what's more readable to other maintainers: a `switch` is generally fine as is, but it is harder to read when there are variables from outer scope (eg: before the `switch`) used in each branches especially when the code is old and variables are not typed (eg: Object + cast each time we want to use said variables, making it especially unreadable and hard to fllow).

You can always declare variables inside a `switch` but it less readable (in my opinion) than when done in an `if`:

```
switch (...) {
  case '...': {
    var n = ...;
  }
}
```

Versus:

```
if (...) {
  var n = ...;
}
```

If you want to use a `switch`:

- use methods when possible: the smaller the `switch` block, the easier it will be to read it. Same apply to `if`.
- Use `enum` for your `ParentType` because the compiler **can** help you: if the `switch` does not have a `default` case, the compiler will issue an error. You won't get that with `String` and `int` even if you can have the compiler fails for `switch` without `default`.
- [Try `switch` evolution available in Java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/switch-expressions.html#GUID-BA4F63E3-4823-43C6-A5F3-BAA4A2EF3ADC): this is similar to using methods; I can't say something good or bad because I rarely used them (I would have to be in Java 17 for that).
- You could also try to not use `switch`: if your `parents` are a finite set, then you could try using enums or a couple of class with one interface.

  enum ParentType {
  TYPE1 {
  public void doSomething(Context ctx) {
  if(ctx.partent1.contains(ctx.childType1)) {
  // ...
  }
  }
  },;

  ```
  public abstract void doSomething(Context ctx);
  ```

  }

  record Context(Object parten1, Object childType1) {}

And use it:

```
Map<String, String> children = parentDataHolder.getParent(parentType).getChildren();
parentType.doSomething(new Context(parten1, childType1));
```

The main points are:

1. enumerate are finite: you are sure your switch handle all "parent type"; all that remains is a possible `null` check if there are case where it can be logically `null`.
2. use an class to hold variables. You may already have that if you are inside a `class` with attributes: I simply used a `record` here which is available in Java 17.